# ASP.NET MVC 2 and VS 2010 Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a VPS and I would like to be able to run ASP.NET MVC 2 apps that were built in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

Which ASP.NET MVC 2 do I need to install (is it Preview 2?) and where can I get the installer for it since all I can find are MVC 2 RC for VS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Framework 3.5 SP1 on the server, and copy System.Web.Mvc.dll to the bin directory, then it will work. You can extract the DLL from the GAC of the machine you have Visual Studio 2010 on. (Perhaps you have some other references too, that you will need to copy).